# Logic of remove entity from dbContext in controller or repository service?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm making simple WebAPI in .NET6 using EntityFramework, which storage data in-memory. API will operate on data in dbContext, and its controller will call those based on incoming requests (Get, Post, Put, Delete).

I'm wondering what the method in the controller for deleting entities should look like so that it can be done properly (I would like to learn how to do it properly). I currently have this function in the controller

```
        [HttpDelete("id")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteProduct(int id)
        {
            await _productRepository.Delete(id);
            return Ok();
        }
```

and delete function in repo

```
        public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
            // var p = await dbContext.FindAsync(typeof(Product), id);
            var p = await dbContext.Products.FindAsync(id);
            if (p == null)
                return;
            dbContext.Products.Remove(p);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return;
        }
```

But in this case, if someone sends a request, they don't know if the entity was deleted successfully, they actually don't know anything. I am thinking about this approach and the question is whether it is correct or whether such things should be done differently (maybe different return type in repository service then check in controller what value was returned then response)

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var entity = _repository.GetEntityById(id);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        return NotFound(); // 404 error
    }

    _repository.DeleteEntity(entity);
    return NoContent(); // 204 error
}
```

This approach makes 2 actions in controller method: find then remove, that's why I'm considering whether this shouldn't be in the repository method.

Comment: `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync` gives you the number of rows affected so you could return a boolean from the `Delete` method in your repository, e.g. `var numRows = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); return numRows > 0;`

Comment: Just a thought: If someone is trying to delete an entity with an id that does not exist.... return "NotFound" (404 - Not Found) or "Deleted" (204 - No Content). - I personally _log_ such a miss (for attack detection and possibly debugging the UI) but return just 204. What is the UI / User supposed to do after they tried to delete something that is not in the DB anyway? It's gone - great. If logs of this accumulate, inform UI Team of possible Bug.

Comment: There's probably far more to deleting a Product, like checking for dependent data, but that aside, create a stub Product (a `Product` object with just an `Id`) and simply delete it without exception handling. Handle exceptions in an exception filter. If the record wasn't there (for whatever reason), it'll be a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

Comment: Define what exception to use for each case you want to handle, and handle that in middleware. So your repository can throw for example NotFoundException when not found, the controller only handles logic when opreations are successfully done. The middleware will handle NotFoundException and return what you like it to.

Comment: @Fildor thanks you mentioned it because I was thinking about it same way !

Comment: @GertArnold didn't know there is something like exception filter, but this sounds like good approach and i will go this way for now

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF Core 7, to remove one or more entities, you should use **ExecuteDelete()** :

```
int deletedRows = dbContext.Products.Where(c => c.id == 1).ExecuteDelete();
```

so you don't need to **Find** and then **Remove** (generating 2 SQL command rows). Only one SQL DELETE FROM...WHERE will be used. And if, meanwhile, someone else deleted the same data, you will not have an exception.

Place it anywhere, in your code, and you won't have to worry about anything else.

P.S. If you are using an earlier version of EF Core, you can use **dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sqlcommand)** to send a "DELETE FROM...": it's always faster than "find and remove" because, in this case also, you have not to retrieve anything from the database.